# Django, Python - How do I create a field where the user can only choose a number between 10000 and 100000?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, between

I'm writing a form that a user can fill in in a browser. One of the questions involves selecting a number between 10000 and 100000. How would I go about prompting the user to do this? If they don't, I want a message to pop up in order to get them to actually pick a number between 10000 and 100000. The variable that deals with this particular figure is called **borrowing**. The data on the form is currently saved in a sqlite3 table.

Here is a my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator


class User(models.Model):
    #to store user data

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    company_number = models.CharField(max_length=9)

    filter_choices = (
        ('retail', 'Retail'),
        ('professional services', 'Professional Services'),
        ('food & drink', 'Food & Drink'),
        ('entertainment', 'Entertainment'),
    )
    business_sector = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=filter_choices)
    days = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    reason_for_loan = models.CharField(max_length=2000)

    #borrowing = models.IntegerField(choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 1)], blank=True)
    #borrowing = models.IntegerField((validators=[MaxValueValidator(100),MinValueValidator(1)])
    borrowing = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(100)])

    if 10000 <= borrowing <= 100000:
        #borrowing = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.firstname
```

As you can see I've tried a bunch of stuff with borrowing with no luck.

This is my **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class UserForm(forms.Form):

    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    telephone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    company_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_street_address = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    postcode = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    company_number = forms.CharField(max_length=9)

    filter_choices = (
        ('retail', 'Retail'),
        ('professional services', 'Professional Services'),
        ('food & drink', 'Food & Drink'),
        ('entertainment', 'Entertainment'),
    )

    business_sector = forms.ChoiceField(choices = filter_choices)

    days = forms.CharField(max_length=5)
    reason_for_loan = forms.CharField(max_length=2000,widget=forms.Textarea)

    borrowing = forms.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(10000),MaxValueValidator(100000)])




##    business_sector = forms.CharField(  
##        ('retail', 'retail'),
##  ('professional_services', 'professional_services'),
##  ('food_&_drink', 'food_&_drink'),
##  ('entertainment', 'entertainment'))
```

This is my **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from users.forms import UserForm
from users.models import User

# the function executes with the signup url to take the inputs 
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  # if the form has been filled
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # creating user data

            user_obj = form.save()
            return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'user_obj': user_obj,'is_registered':True })  # Redirect after POST

            firstname = request.POST.get('firstname', '')
            surname = request.POST.get('surname', '')
            email = request.POST.get('email', '')
            telephone_number = request.POST.get('telephone_number', '')
            company_name = request.POST.get('company_name', '')
            company_street_address = request.POST.get('company_street_address', '')
            city = request.POST.get('city', '') 
            postcode = request.POST.get('postcode', '') 
            company_number = request.POST.get('company_number', '')
            form = request.POST.get('form', '')
            business_sector = request.POST.get('business_sector', '')
            borrowing = request.POST.get('borrowing', '')        
            days = request.POST.get('days', '')
            reason_for_loan = request.POST.get('reason_for_loan', '')

            user_obj = User(firstname=firstname, surname=surname, email=email,
            telephone_number=telephone_number,company_name=company_name,
                    company_street_address=company_street_address,city=city,
                    postcode=postcode,company_number=company_number,
                    business_sector=business_sector,borrowing=borrowing,
                    days=days,reason_for_loan=reason_for_loan)

            # saving all the data in the current object into the database
    else:
        form = UserForm()  # an unboundform
        return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'form': form})

#the function executes with the showdata url to display the list of registered users
def showdata(request):
    all_users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'users/showdata.html', {'all_users': all_users, })
```

This is my **html**:

```
<!-- The alert box to be shown when the submit button is clicked-->
{% if is_registered %}
    <script>alert("You are successfully registered with your new business with:{{user_obj.company_name }} and Email: {{ user_obj.email }}")</script>
    {% else %}
    <form action="{% url 'users:signup' %}"  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endif %}
<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) at all!

You should use Django's [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/) and you just made you life easier!

So, you should leave your models untouched (you may remove the `validators` argument as well) and change the `forms.py` to this:

```
# forms.py

from .models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_borrowing(self):
       borrowing = self.cleaned_data['borrowing']
       if not 10000 < borrowing < 100000:
           raise forms.ValidationError("Your error message here")
       return borrowing
```

Finally in your `views.py` save yourself some time and write:

```
# views.py

def signup(request):

    # GET request. Create an unbound form
    form = UserForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':  # if the form has been filled
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Form is valid. Because the Form (ModelForm) is bound to the User model, then it will create, save in db and return the instance automatically.
            user_obj = form.save()
            return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'user_obj': user_obj,'is_registered':True })  # Redirect after POST

    return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I get the following error:
 
"from .model import User

ImportError: No module named model" 

This is in reference to forms.py

Comment: Forgot an `s`. Typo thing. Its `from .models import User`

Comment: Ahh okay. It's working to a degree. If I put in a number thats under 10000 or over 100000 it just goes to a page that says:

ValueError at /users/signup
The User could not be created because the data didn't validate.

I don't think the code likes the "raise." Do you know how I can get around this?

Comment: Ah! Forgot the call to the `is_valid()` method. Now, it should work.

Comment: Ahh Okay I've done that. I had to defind the "form" variable a little earlier in order for my script to work. I've updated how it looks now. I get a different error now: "ValueError at /users/signup"

Comment: Ahh I'm still getting the same error:

"ValueError at /users/signup
The view users.views.signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138000/discussion-between-nik-m-and-ragnampiza).

Answer (score 1):

You would put that kind of validation code in the form. [Read the docs for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/).

For example:

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):

   ...

   def clean_borrowing(self):
       borrowing = self.cleaned_data['borrowing']
       if not 10000 < borrowing < 100000:
           raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a borrowing value between " \
                                       "10000 and 100000")

       return borrowing
```

Comment: I added your code to the end but now the field is missing in the browser when I run the server:

class User(models.Model):
    #to store user data

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
..
   def clean_borrowing(self):

       borrowing = self.cleaned_data['borrowing']

       if not 10000 < borrowing < 100000:

           raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a borrowing value 
between 10000 and 100000")

       return borrowing